# Can any one explain the below code that i didn't understood?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the code below.  Can someone please give me an explanation?

```
function deviceNameChange() {           
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    {
        var val=xmlHttp.responseText;

        var val1=val.split(',');

        for(var i=0;i<val1.length;i++)
        {
            if(document.getElementById("deviceName").value!=val1[i])
            {
              var anOption = document.createElement("OPTION");      
              document.getElementById("deviceName").options.add(anOption);
              anOption.value=val1[i];
              anOption.innerHTML=val1[i];
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Exactly what don't you understand about it?

Comment: var val1=val.split(',');

Comment: @satish does it hurt to google the method name?

Comment: if(document.getElementById("deviceName").value!=val1[i])

Comment: So, you don't know JavaScript?

Comment: Yes exactly while i was working in some controller i had to see this javascript file

Comment: If you're just after how the *split* method works, then MDN is your best bet: [*MDN String.prototype.split()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Since I didn't know javascript i asked this question and thank you for all your replies.

Comment: BTW, [*option elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-option-element) can't contain markup, so instead of `anOption.innerHTML=val1[i]` it would be better to have `anOption.text=val1[i]`. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the return from a HTTP Request of for example**

> test.php

*For more information:*

[HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

```
var val=xmlHttp.responseText;
             var val1=val.split(',');
         for(var i=0;i<val1.length;i++)
         {
             if(document.getElementById("deviceName").value!=val1[i])
             {
```

**val is the data we got from the request. It must be a string with**

> ,

**because it will get splitted by this.**

*For more information:*

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

**For every**

> i (i is the splitted argument)

**in this string it will create an element and insert the value we got from request.**

Comment: Thank you #Maurize your answer is helpful